# Typescript not type validating values in array of string union types

Tags: typescript

I have the following definitions:

```
type FruitType = 'Apple' | 'Orange' | 'Banana';
interface SurveyValues {
  favoriteFruit: FruitType;
  fruitAllergies: FruitType[];
}

// Everything correctly defined and no problems
const test1 = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Orange', // OK
  fruitAllergies: ['Apple','Banana'] // OK
} as SurveyValues;

const test2 = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Pizza', // Typescript correctly complains
  fruitAllergies: ['Apple','Banana'] // OK
} as SurveyValues;

const test3 = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Orange', // OK
  fruitAllergies: ['Pizza','Candy'] // ??? Typescript Doesn't complain ???
} as SurveyValues;
```

I am not understanding why test 3's fruitAllergies values are considered "valid" by Typescript. Is this a limitation? Is this because I'm casting a generic Object to SurveyValues using as syntax?

I'm using TypeScript 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see errors on the second two variable assignments [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20FruitType%20%3D%20'Apple'%20%7C%20'Orange'%20%7C%20'Banana'%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20SurveyValues%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20FruitType%3B%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20FruitType%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Everything%20correctly%20defined%20and%20no%20problems%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Orange'%2C%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Apple'%2C'Banana'%5D%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%7D%20as%20SurveyValues%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Pizza'%2C%20%2F%2F%20Typescript%20correctly%20complains%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Apple'%2C'Banana'%5D%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%7D%20as%20SurveyValues%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Orange'%2C%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Pizza'%2C'Candy'%5D%20%2F%2F%20%3F%3F%3F%20Typescript%20Doesn't%20complain%20%3F%3F%3F%0D%0A%7D%20as%20SurveyValues%3B)

That said, I prefer to type the variables vs. `as` the objects. The errors are more succinct.

```
type FruitType = 'Apple' | 'Orange' | 'Banana';
interface SurveyValues {
  favoriteFruit: FruitType;
  fruitAllergies: FruitType[];
}

// Everything correctly defined and no problems
const test1: SurveyValues = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Orange', // OK
  fruitAllergies: ['Apple', 'Banana'] // OK
};

const test2: SurveyValues = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Pizza', // ERROR HERE
  fruitAllergies: ['Apple','Banana'] // OK
}

const test3: SurveyValues = {
  favoriteFruit: 'Orange', // OK
  fruitAllergies: ['Pizza','Candy'] // ERROR HERE
}
```

[Second Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20FruitType%20%3D%20'Apple'%20%7C%20'Orange'%20%7C%20'Banana'%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20SurveyValues%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20FruitType%3B%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20FruitType%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Everything%20correctly%20defined%20and%20no%20problems%0D%0Aconst%20test1%3A%20SurveyValues%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Orange'%2C%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Apple'%2C%20'Banana'%5D%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test2%3A%20SurveyValues%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Pizza'%2C%20%2F%2F%20Typescript%20correctly%20complains%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Apple'%2C'Banana'%5D%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test3%3A%20SurveyValues%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20favoriteFruit%3A%20'Orange'%2C%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%20%20fruitAllergies%3A%20%5B'Pizza'%2C'Candy'%5D%20%2F%2F%20%3F%3F%3F%20Typescript%20Doesn't%20complain%20%3F%3F%3F%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I obviously created an analogous code example to weed out confusion. I too get your results, but with my actual definition I still get the problem. And I can't see how my real code is different (materially) than what I posted...
Having said that, if I do "type the variable" like your preference, I do in fact get a compiler error... but not if I do "as XXX". How strange. I will investigate more.
Thank you for your help.